# What coarseness of grind works best for cold brew?

Tags: cold-brew

I recently received [a new device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009MZ67Q) for making cold brew coffee. It put out a really good cold brew. The filter is made out of a fine nylon mesh.

How coarsely (or finely) should the coffee be ground for best cold-brew extraction?

Comment: This is a bit broad, you need to narrow this down a bit, plus there are a couple cold brew questions already: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-brew

Comment: Welcome to [coffee.se]! Your question doesn't quite fit the Q/A style of [se]; please take a minute to take [the tour](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at the [help]. How about restricting to "What characteristics of beans are best suited to cold-brew?" I'd be happy to change this around as an example; let me know. See also: [this question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/481/262) talks about grind; other questions tagged [tag:cold-brew].

Comment: As an example, I trimmed your question down to just one question and formatted it in a way that I'd suggest for this site; hope you don't mind. +1 for an interesting topic, about which we didn't yet have a question!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm learning the ropes. I appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two guides do have specific (though differing!) recommendations on coarseness of grind for cold brew.

- Blue Bottle recommends [a grind **a bit finer** than paper-filtered drip coffee](https://bluebottlecoffee.com/preparation-guides/cold-brew) (they compare it to the same grind as for AeroPress); they're using an immersion setup with a wool filter.
- Kicking Horse recommends [a **medium-coarse** grind](http://www.kickinghorsecoffee.com/en/blog/how-make-cold-brew-coffee), nearly like that of French press; they are using a similar setup but claim that a finer grind extracts more bitter compounds.

Personally, I use the latter because I find the filtering goes more easily with a coarser grind; see also [this question about making cold brew easier to filter](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/431/how-can-i-make-filtering-my-cold-brew-easier).

[This question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/481/whats-the-recommended-coffee-to-water-ratio-for-cold-brew) also discusses the grind. See also related questions with the tag [cold-brew](/questions/tagged/cold-brew).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above listed guides I have also found another two to answer your question.

Prima Coffee recommends a [medium to fine grind](https://prima-coffee.com/blog/what-everyone-ought-know-about-iced-coffee-cold-brew-31371). They are using an AeroPress with 2 filters. They do suggest that at least one of those filters are paper.

ChestBrew has a how-to video that demonstrates the process of making cold brew from start to finish.  Their [whole bean coffee](http://www.chestbrew.com/how-to) packaging suggests a medium coarse grind.

My husband and I are huge cold brew coffee fans and we prefer the second option because we've found that too fine a grind makes the coffee taste burnt and too harsh a grind makes the coffee too bitter. The medium coarse seems to make it just right.  However, we use a pitcher and a milk bag to make our cold brew which I feel may make a difference in overall taste as compared to the device you referenced in your question.

Hope this helps and good luck!