# Breville Smart Grinder Pro setting for cold drip

Tags: drip-brew, grinder, cold-brew

I've been trying to find the best grind size to use in my Bruer cold drip setup.
I bought a Breville Smart Grinder Pro (highly recommended).

Has anyone used this grinder before, and if so what grind size would be the best for cold drip?  Thanks

Comment: For coarseness specifically for [tag:cold-brew], see [this question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/what-coarseness-of-grind-works-best-for-cold-brew). Is that the same as your question?

Answer (score 2):

While I do not own a Smart Grinder Pro, most local places that make cold brew/drip use a medium-fine grind. This picture below can give you a good illustration on how coarse you want your bean. 
[image]

It is really preference, however, I have found that too fine of a grind (like espresso) will usually muddy up a filter and make it harder to pass through due to the lack of pressure. I am sure there is a setting guide either that comes with the box or online that you can use for drip/cold drip. Just remember to keep it coarse enough so that it does not come out too "powdery".

Image source: http://www.bruer.co/blogs/news/12222337-cold-bruer-experiments-with-grind-size

Edit: My recommendation is to use the "Drip Grind" coarseness. That means, a grind that is not as powdered down as espresso; grinds should be no larger that ~1-1.5mm in diameter. Usually the finer a grind is, the more pressure is needed to account for the surface area created.

Comment: Nice illustration. Is that your image? Otherwise, would you cite the source?

Comment: Which of those are you recommending? You say medium-fine; you mean something between what is labeled as "espresso" and "drip"? Also I think you mean "too ***fine*** of a grind (like espresso)" -- you had said "coarse" in place of "find". Can you clarify?